# Predefines for iPhone os and mac os

Tags: iphone, macros, window

As im working on a game engine for my company. i got in the setup fase and i need some predefines to check the os on the device / desktop. I need predefines to check when ever the target os is windows / mac or iphone os. Can any one help me with that? god bless you in advance :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know (which admittedly isn't far) you can check for #if TARGET_OS_WIN32 or #if TARGET_OS_MAC or #if TARGET_OS_IPHONE for wether or not its that device.

I hope this helps!